# Laravel Relation belongTo whereHas

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent-relationship

i have google for 2 days almost and i can't find where i am missing

My goal is From the table Customers get the contacts from the table Customers_Contacts for that i have this 2 relations:

My Customers model:

```
class Customers extends Model{
   protected $table = 'customers';

   public function customerscontacts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CustomersContacts', 'id_customer', 'id');
   }
}
```

My CustomersContacts model:

```
class CustomersContacts extends Model{
 protected $table = 'customers_contacts';
    
    public function Customers(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customers', 'id', 'id_customer');
    }

}
```

My query:

```
$data = Customers::where(function ($query) use ($searchNome) {
                            foreach ($searchNome as $value) {
                                $query->WhereRaw("UPPER(nome) LIKE '%{$value}%'");
                            }
                        });
                        
    if($email){   $data = $data->whereHas('customerscontacts', function($query) use($email) {
                             $query->whereRaw("UPPER(contact) = '{$email}'")->where('type','email');
            });}
            
     if($contacto){   $data = $data->whereHas('customerscontacts', function($query) use($contacto) {
                             $query->where('contact',$contacto)->orwhere('contact',$contacto)->where('type','!=','email');
    });}

$data = $data->get();
```

This code is searching and getting the results from the table Customers, but the results don't show the table customers_contacts.
Sorry i am new with relations in laravel.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you want to load customerscontacts() relation?

Comment: At the moment with this i get all the customer information from the table customers, what i want is the table customers and the table customers_contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all .. you should fix the relation:

```
 public function Customers(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customers','id_customer');
    }
```

the second argument for belongsTo relation must be the foreign key like in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

then to load customers_contacts you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$data = Customers::with('customerscontacts')->where(function ($query) use ($searchNome) {
                            foreach ($searchNome as $value) {
                                $query->WhereRaw("UPPER(nome) LIKE '%{$value}%'");
                            }
                        });
// ........
```

now inside $data you will got a collection of Customers, and inside every one of 'Customers' you should find another collection 'customerscontacts' ..